# Python - Fastest and most efficent way to convert a list-like string to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I'm writting a python program which has to run a c++ program (compiled) in order to manage a very heavy load opperation.

The way I call this executable is subprocess.check_output()

Doing so, it returns a very long string like the following:

`executable_output_1 = [0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]`

`executable_output_2 = [4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]`

`type(executable_output) >>> <type 'str'>`

In this example I wrote a quite short string, but in the real output it's really long.

I'd like to do some operations with that data back in python, so I need a list of lists (as I'll call that executable multiple times).

How could I convert that string into a list of lists?

Desired output:

`executables_outputs_list = [[[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]], [[4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]]]`

`type(executable_output_list) >>> <type 'list'>`

`type(executable_output_list[0]) >>> <type 'list'>`

`type(executable_output_list[0][0][0]) >>> <type 'float'>`

Comment: I would like to see the code with the subprocess.check_output() call.

Comment: @Back2Basics It's quite simple: `check_output(['/home/user/executable', '/home/user/image.png'])`

Comment: Well, you can likely split on the `=` and wrap the string in `[` and `]` then use  `ast.literal_eval`. Ugly, and hackey for sure.

Comment: @Back2Basics `executable_output_1 = check_output(['/home/user/executable', '/home/user/image.png'])` It's not just the image,  but some data processed from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> executable_output = '[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]'
>>> literal_eval(executable_output)
([0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573])
```

This is a `tuple`. To convert to a `list`:

```
>>> list(literal_eval(executable_output))
[[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of python's `json` package which should be faster than the `ast.literal_eval`.

```
# setup
from ast import literal_eval
import json

executable_output_1 = "[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]"
executable_output_2 = "[4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]"

outputs = (executable_output_1, executable_output_2)
```

The `json` approach has the following timing: `100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop`:

```
def extract(output_strings):
    template = '{{"values": [{}]}}'
    parse_func = lambda x: json.loads(template.format(x))
    return [parse_func(x)["values"] for x in output_strings]

extract(outputs)

>>> [[[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]],
     [[4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]]]
```

The `ast` approach is 3x slower for the dummy data with `10000 loops, best of 3: 51.6 µs per loop`:

```
def extract_ast(output_strings):
    return [list(literal_eval(x)) for x in output_strings]

extract_ast(outputs)

>>> [[[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]],
     [[4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]]]
```

The `json` approach improves with increasing amount of data to be parsed. With the following setup, the `json` approach yields `1000 loops, best of 3: 291 µs per loop` compared to the `ast` with `100 loops, best of 3: 3.95 ms per loop` which is **13x** faster.

```
executable_output_1 = ",".join(["[0.011, 0.544, 2.314], [7.895, 6.477, 2.573]"] * 100)
executable_output_2 = ",".join(["[4.255, 6.235, 7.566], [9.522, 7.321, 1.234]"] * 100)

outputs = (executable_output_1, executable_output_2)
```